# Are this languages can be represented by regular expressions?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

1. The set of all words with the same number of 0’s and 1’s.
2. The set of all words contained in {0,1}* that have an even number of 0’s and an odd number of 1’s.

I guess first one is NO.
Second one seems no too as we get {0,1,00,11,000,111,...}. Not all of them contains even number of 0s and odd number of 1s.

Am I on the right track?
If not, then give me a detailed explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems you have asked this before: [Which of the following languages can be represented by regular expressions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/142653/which-of-the-following-languages-can-be-represented-by-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

For question 1: try to come up with a proof that the language is not regular.

Hint: Let your language be $L$ and suppose towards a contradiction that it is regular. Use the closure properties of regular languages (in particular, regular languages are closed under intersection) to show that there is some regular language $L'$ such that $L \cap L'$ is a well-known non regular language.

Question 2 is not asking you whether all words in $\{0,1\}^*$ contain an even number of $0$s and an odd number of $1$s (that's clearly false). Rather, it wants you to consider the language defined as the set of all possible words (i.e., words from $\{0,1\}^*$) that also satisfy some additional property. This additional property is having both  an even number of $0$s and an odd number of $1$s.

Hint: Try to design a DFA $D$ for this language. Suppose you are reading a word from left-to-right and you want to determine whether it satisfies the above property. What do you need to remember? Encode this information in the  states of $D$.

Answer (score 0):

> The set of all words with the same number of 0’s and 1’s.

Isn't regular.

**Proof (by contradiction):**

Let $\ell=\{w\in\Sigma^*\mid \#w_a=\#w_b\}$, and suppose $\ell$ is regular, and let $M=\{a^nb^n\mid n\geq 0\}$ that $M\subseteq \ell$.

It's clear that $M$ isn't regular, on the other hand, we know that intersection of two regular languages are regular (by construction method on fsm), so
$$\ell\cap a^*b^*=M$$
But $M$ isn't regular and it contradict with the fact that intersection of two regular languages are regular, hence, $\ell$ isn't regular.

> The set of all words contained in {0,1}* that have an even number of
> 0’s and an odd number of 1’s.

[Check this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/142653/which-of-the-following-languages-can-be-represented-by-regular-expressions/142654#142654).